# "use diagnostics" won't work

Tags: perl

Every time I type in the `use diagnostics` in Perl I just get an error message saying

`couldn't find diagnostics data in /file name.etc...`

can someone help please? The `use warnings` etc all work fine!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `use diagnostics;` works fine! Try running this in command-line `perl -e diagnostics`.

Comment: What version of Perl are you running? (perl -v)

Comment: Perhaps you meant that your error was `Can't locate diagnostics.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...`

Comment: @TLP, so, he copied the message correctly up to the file name (`die "couldn't find diagnostic data in $PODFILE @INC $0";`)

Comment: Yes indeed I just didn't put all the information of the file names, which as know can be very long, and not useful in this problem. Basically, it doesn't find the file, I guess because it's not installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This indicates that your installation of Perl did not include perldiag.pod (a documentation file).  See [here](http://grokbase.com/t/perl/perl5-porters/04bbpyed7v/suggestions-to-better-ship-perl-on-os-x).

The easiest solution is probably to update your installation of Perl.  A good idea anyway, unless you already have the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that later on today.

Comment: Doesn't matter what version you run. It's a file that comes with all versions. As such, you have a broken install. dan1111 suggests you reinstall Perl to fix this broken install. In my answer, I posited that it's broken by design by your OS distributor, but all you have to do is install the documentation package.

Answer (score 5):

It can't find `perldiag.pod`, a file that comes with Perl.

Your OS/distro probably separated Perl's documentation files into a separate package. Just install the `perl-doc` package or whatever your distro named it.

Or you could just look up the error message in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking all this out as I mentioned below.

Comment: "perldiag" just brings up "bash: perldiag: command not found" in the Terminal.

Comment: What did I say that makes you think it's a command? It's a documentation file. You could view it using `perldoc perldiag` if you had it, but you don't..

Comment: What's your OS, and if linux, what distribution are you using (Ubuntu? Debian?)

Comment: I just got this error after doing an update on a cygwin installation that have had perl working flawlessly for months. Installing packages perl_manpages and perl_pods (and one more I do not remember the name for now) solved the problem.